# In Apex 19.2, is it possible to display an interactive grid pagination on the left side top and bottom like you can with an interactive report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I originally created an IR but ran into an issue I can't resolve so I tried another approach 
using an IG.  See the screenshots below for reference.

image.[Interactive Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0LcI.png)png

On the above IR, I want the column **General Notes** to display only 30 characters and not wrap.
I have used the **td[headers=xx]** code to set the column width and a myriad of CSS, Inline, etc. 
If I use any **no wrap** options, it sizes to the length of the data in the column.  I just want to display
30 characters no matter the data length.  I have tried using the SUBSTR in my SELECT query to 
limit the column to 30 characters, but then the Search function can only search on those 30 
characters.

Consequently, I created an IG that looks similar and disabled the editing.  The **General Notes**
column can be sized to 30 characters.  This approach works great, but the pagination is on 
the right side bottom of the page!  If I could move the pagination to the left top and bottom,
then this approach will work great!  (The users are accustomed to and desire to keep displaying
the record counts on the left top and bottom.)

image.[Interactive Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMKT3.png)png

So I basically have 2 issues, 1 with the IR and 1 with the IG! Any suggestions will be much 
appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sizing by characters is difficult (at least I find it to be). If you're okay sizing by pixels, you can try the following for the IR. First, assign a static id to the column (I'll use 'my-class' in this example). Right-click the IR region and select **Create Dynamic Action**. That will create a DA that fires on the refresh of the report region. For the Action, set **Type** to **Execute JavaScript Code** and enter the following in the **Code** field:

```
$('td[headers="mgr"]').wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

Ensure that the **Fire on Initialization** attribute is enabled. Next, add the following CSS to the page:

```
td[headers="my-test"] {
  max-width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you'd rather move the pagination in an IG, use the following steps. Add this code to the **Execute when Page Loads** attribute of the page (under JavaScript).

```
$('.a-GV-footer').prepend($('.a-GV-pagination'))
```

And the following to the **Inline** attribute (under CSS):

```
.a-GV-pagination, .a-GV-stateIcons, .a-GV-status {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
}

.a-GV-pagination {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Both of these options worked awesome for what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, Todd! :)